# jquery autocomplete does not fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-autocomplete

I am trying to implement autocomplete into my existing application.  The autcomplete never seems to fire.  Here is my code:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    var availableTags = [
                         "ActionScript",
                         "AppleScript",
                         "Asp",
                         "Scheme"
                       ];

                       $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({

                         source: availableTags
                       });

});

  </script>


            <div class="ui-widget">
                <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
                <input id="tags" type="submit" value="Search">
            </div>
```

My referenced js css files look like the following:

```
<link href="{% static 'css/timePicker.css' %}" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="{% static 'css/jquery-ui.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="{% static 'css/jquery-ui.structure.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="{% static 'css/jquery-ui.theme.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: any error in console??

Comment: no, it finds all the libraries with no problem

Comment: did you load your customscript next to the libraries??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a text input.

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
    <input id="tags" type="text" />
    <input id="tagsSubmit" type="submit" value="Search" />
</div>
```

Comment: how can I do this with input type = submit since my search depends on that?

Comment: The autocomplete widget needs a text input to do the actual searching, once you got it though, you can add a submit button to use the value. In fact in the answer provided you can see I didn't delete the submit button, I only added a text input. When you press enter, it will submit "tags" with the selected value.

Answer (score 1):

Change your input type to `text`: [http://jsfiddle.net/7jwbd70j/](http://jsfiddle.net/7jwbd70j/1/)